# Complex roots of a complex polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

> In an Argand plane, $A(z_1), B(z_2), C(z_3)$ are distinct complex numbers lying on the curve $\;|z| = \sqrt 3$.
>
> If a root of $z_1z^2 + z_2z + z_3 = 0$ has a modulus equal to unity then $z_1, z_2, z_3$ are in
>
> a) Arithmetic progression
>
> b) Geometric Progression
>
> c) Harmonic Progression
>
> d) All of these

Firstly I assumed root to be $a$ and then put it in the equation. Then I took the conjugate of the whole equation as $\bar a= 1/a$ and $\bar z_i= 3/z_i\; (i=1,2,3)$. I have concluded the other root to be unimodular as well and the angle between roots is 120 deg but I am unable to get a relation between $z_1,z_2,z_3$.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please
use MathJax.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see
e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and
[equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).

Comment: Please explain what are $AP,GP,HP $.

Comment: Arithmetic Progression, Geomettric Progression , Harmonic progression

Comment: At the risk of showing my ignorance of the syntax, please explain what $A(z_1), B(z_2), C(z_3)$ represent.  If you had said that $\sqrt{3} = |z_1| = |z_2| = |z_3|$, this I would have understood.  Is this what you intend, or do you intend something else by the phrasing $A(z_1), B(z_2), C(z_3)$?